# Binding Property to usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I got a usercontrol containing a dependancy property of the typ list (this sits inside an library / also tried with a normal property).

```
public partial class PicSelection : UserControl
{
    #region Properties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LstImagesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LstImages", typeof(List<string>), typeof(PicSelection), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    // .NET Property wrapper
    public List<string> LstImages
    {
        get { return (List<string>)GetValue(LstImagesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LstImagesProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion
    ...
```

I also got a DataClass:

```
public class Data : BaseObject
{
    #region Members
    public List<string> Images { set { SetValue("Images", value); } get { return (GetValue<List<string>>("Images")); } }
    #endregion


    #region Construction
    public GameData()
    {
        Images = new List<string>();
        Images.Add("pack://application:,,,/TestApp;component/Content/Images/Pictures/0002.jpg");
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Base object is used to automatically create dependance properties:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class BaseObject : PropertyNotifier
{
    #region Members
    private readonly IDictionary<string, object> _values = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    #endregion
```

Now I want to bind the Data.Images to the customcontrol.LstImages ("Data" is a property of typ Data on the page, where the control is used). The program works without exception but somehow the LstImages in the control, I checked it on several events, is always null.

```
<controls:PicSelection Name="SelPic" LstImages="{Binding Data.Images}" Foreground="White" FontSize="16"/>
```

On the other hand, to do the same thing with a static class (which is almost the same relating to the organisation) per

```
<usercontrol SomeArray="{x:Static data:StaticClass.TheStrings}"/>
```

is so simple. It even works with normal properties. The setting of Datacontext to this changes nothing by the way. Have I overlooked something?

Comment: What's in the visual studio output window? You should see binding errors in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked in the output window? Normally if binding fails silently, you will see some errors in there.

You need to check what is a data context that's being passed into PicSelection control. Can you try setting data context explicitly and then binding directly to the Images property?

```
LstImages="{Binding Path=Images}"
```

Comment: That was a great advise. But the output also doesn't shows that everything is was loaded correctly.

Comment: Can you copy what's in the output window so that we can see?

Comment: Thank you very much - you let me to the error. Setting the Context without path doesn't work. But setting the DataContext directly to Data compined with Path works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Read up http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/. It has some very useful stuff on there.

Answer (score 0):

If instance of `Data` is the `DataContext` of your `UserControl` then you need to update your `Binding` as

```
<controls:PicSelection Name="SelPic" LstImages="{Binding Images}" Foreground="White" FontSize="16"/>
```

Comment: Of course. I tried to set the datacontext to "this" (the page which contains Data). Anyway, I tried it this way - doesn't work.